# How to find starting point and endpoint at coordinate list?

Tags: python, algorithm, classification, coordinates, sequence

I'm reaching out for help with an algorithm.

I created a random dataset 'coords_list' by following the process below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10000, 100)
x = x.astype(int)

x1 = x[(x > 3000)]
y1 = x1 + 3000
points1 = list(zip(x1, y1))

x2 = x[((x > 3000) & (x < 5000)) | ((x > 6000) & (x < 8000))]
y2 = x2 + 2000
points2 = list(zip(x2, y2))

x3 = x[((x > 4000) & (x < 6000)) | ((x > 7000) & (x < 8000))]
y3 = x3 + 1000
points3 = list(zip(x3, y3))

x4 = x[(x > 2000) & (x < 7000)]
y4 = x4
points4 = list(zip(x4, y4))

coords_list = points1 + points2 + points3 + points4
coords_list = sorted(coords_list)
```

Using only the information from the 'coords_list', I want to write a function whose behavior is to find the start and end points of each block(chain) as shown in the picture above.

[Figure 1. Problem design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEuNm.png)

Initially, I wanted to read all the coordinates sorted by x-coordinate, store each coordinate in a different list per block (chain), and categorize the first and last elements in the list as start and end points.

However, it was very difficult to dynamically link multiple coordinates with the same x-coordinate to the each block (chain).

[Figure 2. What I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQYsl.png)

Looking at the top of Figure 2, I was trying to put the coordinates for the duplicate x-coordinates into each list and then dynamically concatenate them back to each block (chain), but this behavior was difficult to implement.

The result I was hoping to achieve with this behavior is shown in the lower portion of Figure 2.

However, when I rethought the problem, I realized that I didn't need all the classifications for these coordinates, I just needed the coordinates of the start and end points of each block (chain) (as shown in the problem design in Figure 1).

So, I was wondering if there are any algorithms that you could recommend to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem using DFS
[image: Solved_problem]

This is my code.

```
def dfsChaining(coords_list, visited, start_idx):
chain = []
stack = [start_idx] 
visited[start_idx] = True

while stack:
    current_idx = stack.pop()
    chain.append(coords_list[current_idx])
    
    for neighbor_idx, neighbor in enumerate(coords_list):
        if not visited[neighbor_idx] : 
            if isNeighbor(coords_list[current_idx], neighbor): 
                stack.append(neighbor_idx)
                visited[neighbor_idx] = True

return chain

def isNeighbor(coord1, coord2): 
condition = abs(coord1[0] - coord2[0]) <= 103 and abs(coord1[1] - coord2[1]) <= 103
return condition

visited = [False] * len(coords_list)
chains = []

for i in range(len(coords_list)):
if not visited[i]: # if visited[i] is False
    chain = dfsChaining(coords_list, visited, i)
    chains.append(chain)

chain_start_end_coords = [(chain[0], chain[-1]) for chain in chains]

for i, (start, end) in enumerate(chain_start_end_coords):
print(f"Chain {i + 1}: Start {start}, End {end}")
```

Comment: You can use the isNeighbor function by accepting a distance as an argument to the function that is not an constant value of 103.